# sibling route not update in browser url bar when change ngbNav and navigate to sibling route

Tags: angular

I have app.routing.ts lazy load route

```
  {
    path: 'users/view,
    loadChildren: () => import("./modules/view-user/view-user.module").then((m) => m.ViewUserModule)
  }
```

then in view-user-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ViewUserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'items',
        component: ViewItemsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'shipments',
        component: ViewShipmentsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'activities',
        component: ViewShipmentsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

In my ViewUserComponent i have ngbNav in html file

```
    <ul ngbNav [(activeId)]="activeId" (navChange)="changeTabBySelect($event)">
      <li [ngbNavItem]="'items'">
        <a ngbNavLink>Items</a>
      </li>
      <li [ngbNavItem]="'shipments'">
        <a ngbNavLink>Shipments</a>
      </li>
      <li [ngbNavItem]="'activities'">
        <a ngbNavLink>Activities</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

In component i have function to change route

```
  public changeTabBySelect(ev: NgbNavChangeEvent) {
    this.activeId = ev.nextId;
    this.redirectToSelectedTabUrl(this.activeId);
  }

  redirectToSelectedTabUrl(tab: string) {
    this.router.navigate(
      [tab],
      { queryParamsHandling : 'preserve', relativeTo: this.route, replaceUrl: true }, 
    );
  }
```

when i change the tab then url in browser remain same but tab content will update with component defined with respective route.

**for example:
i have initially items tab selected and url is https://localhost.com/users/view/items?code=PK5894
and when i select tab shipments it should be
https://localhost.com/users/view/shipments?code=PK5894
but it remain same.**

Answer (score 2):

Please Use `replaceState()` function, it might be helpful.

First, Import the library,

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

Second, Tab change function,

```
onChangeTab(url){ this.location.replaceState(url); }
```